# How to change theme for button?

Tags: android, button, themes

in my app I use my own theme "Theme.prehladna" where I use 'default' theme "Theme" as a parent theme. Problem is that parent theme "Theme" contains theme for all buttons: Center vertically/horizontally. I'd need to remove vertical centering. (If I know how, then I can change other settings). Below is also my theme for button called "Bttn.center" where parent theme is widget.button (centered horizontally, vertically). I've tried to change button theme in Theme.prehladna (line  and below it) but it doesn't work (shows error No resource found) this way. Can you help how to edit my code in order to do what I need?

****UPDATE:****
Code below has been corrected, but I still have button centered horizontally as well as vertically. Code below somehow does not affect my button. P.S. Theme.prehladna is applied on activity in android manifest. What do I do wrong?

styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Prehladna" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

<!-- Button styles -->
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Bttn.center</item> <<<<<<here Eclipse says No resource found<<<<<<<
CORRECT CODE: 
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Bttn.center</item> 

</style>

<style name="Bttn.center" parent="android:Widget.Button">        
<item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>      
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `@android:style/Bttn.center`, but your style is not a default style included in the Android framework. Use this instead:
`@style/Bttn.center`

Comment: thank you. It does not show error anymore. Just one thing. When I use code above, button is still centered horizontally as well as vertically. What do I do wrong?

Comment: hmm, is the theme applied correctly? I can't see why it shouldn't work.